# Unable to connect to Linux git Repo from Windows machine

Tags: linux, windows, git, ubuntu

So recently I've been trying to set up a Git server to manage personal projects and work. I created a bare Git repo on a spare laptop running Ubuntu and I installed Git Bash on my Windows machine. Right now I'm having some issues in actually being able to clone my Ubuntu git server to my Windows computer.

I used `git remote add origin myserver@myserver-Dell-System:/home/myserver/CentralRepo.git` but
whenever I try to clone to my Windows machine, Git bash spits out this error:

```
ssh: Could not resolve hostname myserver@myserver-Dell-System: Name or service not known
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights and repository exists.
```

I double checked my add to make sure the address of my Git server was correct and I assume Git bash for Windows comes with OpenSSH.

Does anyone know why this is happenning and how I can get my Windows machine to sucessfully clone from a server to itself? Thanks!

Comment: Step 1: Make sure you can ping the machine's IP address. Step 2: Make sure it's name resolves via DNS (ping its hostname). Step 3: Make sure you can SSH to the machine. Then git should work. Setting up servers and configuring networking is off-topic here.

Comment: Oh okay I see. Sorry about the off topic post; maybe that's why this post got downvoted 3 times =/. I'll try what you mentioned

Comment: @David47295 This is on topic (I have answer a tons of questions about similar topic), but the reviewers are not experienced in the git tag, and haven't seen such questions. So in their mind, it is "off-topic".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A valid ssh url would be

```
auser@myserver-Dell-System
```

You can check if you can resolve and connect to that server with

```
ssh -T auser@myserver-Dell-System
```

That supposes that you have generated a public/private ssh key pair, and added your public key to `~auser/.ssh/authorized_keys` file first.
See "[Adding SSH Keys to authorized_keys](https://askubuntu.com/a/46425/5470)"